# Difference between 5.5.43-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log and 5.5.43-log version of mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there any difference in below two version of mysql if yes then what are the differences? any reference would be helpful.

As both version is same but the licence type is different -

**5.5.43-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log**

**MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)**

**5.5.43-log**

**MySQL Community Server (GPL)**

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could have simply checked out mysql's website on [the different products](https://www.mysql.com/products/). To see the difference between community edition and any commercial editions, see items marked with 1 in the feature list.

Answer (score 0):

Both are different version as first one is Enterprise version whereas second one commercial version.
Reason for showing -log at the end is showing because any one of the below logs were enabled by default, which caused the "-log" available while fetching the version information using below query.

Binary log
Slow log
General query log

if -log is not showing then enable any one log from the above and restart the database will fix the issue.

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Cheers,
Suraj